# How to follow a log until a string is matched in PowerShell

Tags: docker, powershell, grep

I would like to be able to do something similar to this is PowerShell

`docker logs -f my-container | grep -q "string-to-match"`

i.e. to follow a log file and when a string is matched you stop follow the file. My idea was to try something like this

`docker logs -f my-container | Select-String "string-to-match"`.

I know it's not complete but I can't figure out how to make it work. I also did try to use WSL2 like this

`docker logs -f my-container | wsl grep -q "string-to-match"`.

but it keeps following the log even after a match has been found!

A WSL-solution would solve my problem but a native PowerShell-solution would be preferable!

Comment: Idk if this is possible. For example if you write something like: `docker logs -f my-container | % { Write-Host "== HELLO WORLD == $_" }` you would expect that every line would be prefixed with `== HELLO WORLD ==` but that's not the case. Since `docker` is an executable, I don't think it yields any results that can be processed by PS. Maybe some more knowledgeable ppl know a way.

Comment: Thanks for the input! When I try your example it works as intended (it prefixes every row of the log with "== HELLO WORLD ==").